# Can I ask a question about a problem I cannot reliably reproduce?

Tags: discussion

I'm experiencing a bizarre behavior dealing with a particular feature of Redis. I've been unable to find through Google, forums, official documentation and other resources any similar description of my problem. In fact, the documentation completely contradicts my observations.

At this point it seems practical to reach out to the SO community for help, however there is one thing preventing me from asking. I cannot reliably reproduce this behavior outside of the project. What I'm seeing is seemingly random in that it works ~90% of the time, and only occasionally fails.

I've tried intentionally reproducing this without success. To include a self-contained example, I'd need to provide ~20k lines of code, hope that a reader has a similar infrastructure and has the time to wait for this thing to blow up.

I suspect that if I were to ask this question on SO, that I would be downvoted to oblivion. My question is: Is this type of question suitable for StackOverflow (assuming I don't include the 20k lines of code, but merely a detailed description of the situation)? Should I use another SE site? If so, which one is appropriate?

The only reason I need 20k lines of code to reproduce the issue is because its so incredibly difficult to debug. There is nothing (that is immediately obvious to me) I can do to even gain insight into the origin of the issue. The only way we know it has happened is to experience a random intermittent error and check the logs for a particular pattern. Without elaborating on the issue itself (which is off topic for meta), it is difficult to describe the particular difficulties. I sincerely want to ask a proper question but only if it is welcome.

Comment: The main problem here is the fact that you need 20k lines of code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If you can't provide a reproducible example, but you can provide a *very* clear explanation of why it's impossible to provide a reproducible example, you'll probably be good.

Comment: The key is really that you provide as much useful data as you can. Obviously as much error detail as you can possibly collect. At least some description of what you're doing. Maybe you tried some experiments, and the problem appears/disappears under certain conditions. If you provide detailed information about a problem, and it really looks like something that is difficult to solve, I wouldn't downvote it just because it doesn't have complete code. And if it's in a domain I know, I would try to answer.

Comment: Consider that some things simply aren't possible over the internet. SO is a great tool to be able to get in touch with other developers who may be able to help you out in a pinch; it's not a magic service that can and will solve *all* your problems. If your issue is such that one would need to watch the machine state of a complex system to even see the issue, maybe hiring a consultant is the better tool to use instead of posting on SO. If you *can* come up with a question that is useful to ask over the web, go ahead. If not, tough luck, look for solutions other than SO.

Comment: I doubt that it would get serious downvotes if you explained your process and showed your research. However, if you can't debug it after spending significant time and effort on it and with access to the system, code, and logs, then it's a long shot to expect someone else to debug it from just the description without access to anything.

Comment: This sounds to me like a race condition; but 20k lines of code? Are you counting whitespaces and comments? If it really is 20k lines of _code_, then its best to post it [directly to redis](http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db) - I would vote to close it, but I probably wouldn't downvote (assuming you explained it correctly in the question itself).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In theory, if we can't reproduce it, we can't fix it.  In practice, we don't always reproduce your entire environment to answer your troubleshooting questions, although it is handy to have some code to paste into an IDE to see how it behaves.

Troubleshooting over the Internet is a pattern-matching exercise.  If we've seen your problem before, and we know why it is happening, we'll give you the solution.  That said, "Has anyone experienced this before?" is not necessarily a valid (or answerable) question.

We ask for a way to reproduce the problem, in large part, to get you to demonstrate that you've made a good faith effort to solve the problem yourself.<sup>*</sup>  So if you can provide enough information in your question to make it answerable, then we'll do our best to answer it.

*<sub>If you need 20K lines of code to reproduce the problem, that's pretty strong evidence that you haven't sufficiently narrowed down the problem to make it answerable over the Internet.</sub>

Comment: Please see my edited question. Perhaps that will provide enough information as to why I would need to post 20k lines of code. It is difficult to even begin narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 15):

> I suspect that if I were to ask this question on SO, that I would be downvoted to oblivion.

I hope that you wouldn't be. The hover-text on the downvote button is:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Nobody has to upvote you for presenting your problem clearly and showing your research, but it's not really appropriate to *downvote* questions simply for lack of an easily reproducible problem.

You might be thinking of one of the following off-topic close reasons:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be
>   reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar
>   questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner
>   unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by
>   identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to
>   reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before
>   posting.

I don't think this close reason is really aimed at you. Note the language: "similar questions may be on topic" and "this one *was resolved* in a manner unlikely to help future readers." This is not aimed at every question that contains a typo or doesn't give a way for readers to immediately reproduce the problem. Your question might be *really hard to answer* without the benefit of a way to reproduce the error, but we don't close questions that are difficult to answer (as long as it's *clear what you're asking*).

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**")
>   must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and
>   the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question
>   itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not
>   useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and
>   Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

This might be the one that gets you - depending on the actual content of your question. You can clearly identify the desired behavior since you have code that works, but can you identify a specific problem or error? "It fails 10% of the time" doesn't qualify. You've said that you can't provide an MCVE, but [as Robert points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271199/2359271), your problem may still be recognizable by someone who can offer a solution - or at the very least, provide some insight that would lead you to a solution or an MCVE.

Try to make up for the lack of MCVE by really polishing your question before posting it. Well-posed, well-researched questions don't tend to attract a lot of downvotes unless they're *blatantly* close-worthy.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me in the past. Meaning that I've got a diagnosis and a solution from the community. [Here's one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970007/inexplicable-unsatisfiedlinkerror-on-native-library-load)

"Can't reproduce", oftentimes, is just a way of saying "don't have a test lab large enough", and/or "not running the right kind of test".

Especially relevant in the Android space, with its crazy zoo of devices and OS mods. So ask away, I say.

Answer (score 3):

A possible side question might be asking about how to debug in this specific scenario. When SO can't help you solve the problem, it might help you solve the problem yourself.

This is usually done through comments asking for specific things that you can try to help identify the problem. Asking for it might produce an answer that explains in detail what things you can try, much more than a comment can.

Answer (score -1):

Reproducing issue helps you to understand it clearly and making clear your question is polling for good answer.

Making demo and coding every time means you are able to make a approach for Product. When it seems making hard to reproduce problem i'll break it in several modules and test them individually. Entire environment of coding may affect the demo which is producing issue.