# What should be done about site bugs that cannot be reproduced?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, meta, bug-reporting-process

There're many bug reports *here on Meta Stack Overflow* that have been closed because they cannot be reproduced. Unfortunately, just because a bug cannot be reproduced doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Simply closing these questions does not solve those problems.

One may argue that the development team wouldn't want to waste their time patching a bug that they themselves cannot reproduce. While this is true, what about the unfortunate people who are experiencing these bugs? If there's a major bug that affects Stack Overflow or is detrimental to the user experience, but we cannot reproduce it, *how should we address it?*

**Is there truly nothing we can do to help the unfortunate few who're experiencing bugs that we sadly cannot reproduce?**

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271198

Comment: If a bug falls in the forest and no one can reproduce it, is it a bug? Answer: probably not. The odds of not one meta user being able to reproduce something and an actual bug occurring are... slim to none.

Comment: @hichris123 Closing a question only requires 5 votes. So if a bug report is closed as not reproducible, it doesn't necessarily mean that absolutely nobody is able to reproduce the bug. That bug may just be rare.

Comment: But we have comments and we have reopen votes. And, while I don't have the data on this, I'm sure that the number of questions closed as no-repro is quite quite low.

Comment: slightly altered the title to match your edit explanation. Better to solve the problem at the root rather than explain it away ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep adding information until someone figures out how to reproduce it... Or no one is encountering it anymore.

What else is there to do? If no one can reproduce it, the chances of fixing it are slim (there are exceptions; in some cases it's possible to examine logs or add extra checks to catch intermittent bugs, but even when this is possible it helps to have enough info to narrow down the area where it occurs).

Note that generally bug reports aren't *closed* because the bug can't be reproduced; they'll either be tagged [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) or closed because they lack sufficient information for the nature of the problem to even be identified.

Comment: Meta doesn't have a dedicated bug tracker so it follows different rules from a traditional bug tracker... but in a traditional bug tracker, it's generally preferred to open a new bug rather than reviving old ones as "no repros" are generally too localized to be fixed in the long run.

Comment: Every project will have different customs for how their bug tracker should be used. I would personally prefer that the old bug be "revived" (assuming it is truly the same bug), rather than opening a new one. And I would mark new ones as duplicates of the old bug, because it's better to have all the information in the same place. Just because the original investigator wasn't able to reproduce the problem doesn't mean it's too localized. It just means there wasn't enough information provided or (s)he didn't try hard enough. (It may certainly alter the priority level, though.) @uhoh