# How to ask a question where it's not possible to give code which reproduces the exact problem

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I asked this question, but it was closed with the following message

*[Print works if called from inside for range but doesn't work outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64728516/print-works-if-called-from-inside-for-range-but-doesnt-work-outside)*

> Closed. This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers.

> Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.

As I have written at the end of the question

> The function func() is inside a library I do not have sources for, so I am unable to give fully working program.

So how do I modify this question to get it answered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I ask a question about a problem I cannot reliably reproduce?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271198/can-i-ask-a-question-about-a-problem-i-cannot-reliably-reproduce)

Comment: @gnat - no, it does not. I can reliably reproduce the problem.

Comment: Make this question reproducible without the function. You have something in that variable put there by the function, ideally you could make a similar function that put the same thing in memory, but if you can't, you can serialize the variable and share it, no function needed (unless this is not actually a list, but some object of a library which you can't share, and that seems likely to me).

Comment: Not all problems should/could be brought to SO, some of the are best solved with help of a debugger. It is much faster than writing questions on SO.

Comment: *We* need to be able to reliably reproduce the problem. If it's only reproducible in a context you can't share with us, e.g. due to the libraries or environments involved, we can't help.

Comment: "Fred's garage, how can we help you?"..."my car runs badly"..."OK, bring it in and we'll look at it"...."Oh, I can't do that, can you fix it by email?"..........."click"........."Hello?  Hello?....."

Comment: Consider this from the perspective of the volunteers trying to help you: "How to *answer* a question where it's not possible to give code which reproduces the exact problem?" We literally don't know what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 14):

I believe you have more than one problem on that question.

One is that you are focusing on `print`'s behaviour, which is very likely irrelevant to your issue.

Can you even access `lst[0]`, never mind printing it? Simply assigning it to another variable? By focusing on `print` you have the first distraction, and since the question revolves around that behaviour for an unknown entity (`lst`), it starts derailing the question.

Then you have `func()`, which is yet another distraction. Asking about "what does this code that you can't see does?" is not a recipe for success.

Finally, it seems you are doing very little to inspect and analyse `lst` on your own. My Python is **very** rusty at the moment, but I remember that setting up an interactive debugger was fairly easy, and that one had at the very least access to `type()` to inspect a variable type to begin with.

If you removed all the distractions from the question it would boil to something similar to:

---

#### With what type would be possible to iterate it over as an array but not to access its elements directly?

I have a variable `lst` which I can iterate over like this:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
       print(lst[i])
```

which outputs:

> `['ABC', 'PQR']`

But I can't access its elements directly.

Doing:

```
print lst[0]
```

throws and `IndexError` error.

Attempting to print `lst` itself produces:

> `[['ABC', 'PQR']]`

What type or types could `lst` be to exhibit this behaviour?

---

The question still crucially misses more attempts to introspect the variable (`type()`, `dir()`, or `.__doc__` come to memory, but again I haven't really touched Python in some time).

I don't know if this would be well received by the Pythonic people. I would bet that at the very best it would be a dupe, and the lack of debugging efforts on your part would probably not be received very warmly.

But at least it would remove the focus from the "code beyond sight" problem.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any shape for this question to make sense. The for loop will execute `lst[0]`as well (the first `i` is 0) so this situation is literally impossible as presented. The only way for this situation to "work" is for the library to use non-standard types - which again means we need to know what is inside that black box.